# How to solve $4^{5 - 9x} - 8^{2 -x} = 0$ for complex case?

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, exponentiation

I know it might be a simple question to answer but I am not able to figure out how do I solve such equation for complex cases. I want to solve the equation manually, I tried solving it using the identity

$\log (z^w) = w\log (z) + 2I \pi n$ as mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428420/can-we-ever-use-certain-log-exp-identities-in-the-complex-case) but I think I am getting something wrong.
How do I use log identities for complex cases and solve the equation?
I searched about [complex logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Definition_of_principal_value) but could not figure out how to use here to get the result.

The answer for the equation $4^{5 - 9*x} - 8^{2 -x} = 0$ is $\frac {log(16) + 2I \pi n}{log(32768)}$ as computed [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve(4**(5%20-%209*x)%20-%208**(2%20-%20x),%20x%5C))

Comment: Got it.  So you can rearrange to get $2^{10-18x}=2^{6-3x}$.

Comment: $4=2^2, 8=2^3$, so $4^{5-9x}-8^{2-x}=0\to 2^{10-18x}-2^{6-3x}=0 \to 10-18x=6-3x$

Comment: But this will result in real solution of `x`, I want to get the complex result

Comment: Then take $2^{10-18x}\to 1024-2^{18a+18bi}\to \frac{1024}{2^{18a}\cdot2^{18bi}}$ and equate that to $2^{6-3x}\to \frac{64}{2^{3a}\cdot2^{3bi}}$

Comment: Is there any method using complex logarithm (taking logs)?
I want to get the result as stated in wolframalpha.

Comment: The equation $2^{10-18x}=2^{6-3x}$ can be rearranged to get $2^4=2^{15x}$.  Now you can take logs.

Comment: @lulu I'm somewhat unfamiliar with complex exponential arithmetic not using the base $e$. I would be worried that swapping $4^{5-9x}$ for $2^{10-18x}$ and simplifying the exponents the way you've done removes solutions or adds new ones. Are you certain that this isn't the case?

Comment: @Arthur  Ah...I think everything is ok, but (as you point out) the possibilities for error are legion.  I'll go back to the original and check.

Comment: @Arthur  Standing by what I wrote.  At least, going back to the original and taking logs gives the same set of answers.  As a sanity check (at least) WA agrees.  Your point is well taken, though.  Rapid manipulation of complex exponents can lead to careless errors.  Don't think it happened here though.

Comment: @lulu, but such simplification would not yield result for equations like: $ 4^{x/2} - 2^{x/3} $ or $ 5^{x/2} - 2^{3/x}$

Comment: True.  Squaring (or cubing) both sides would introduce false solutions.  I didn't do anything of that sort.  To be sure, I wasn't positive of that (it's easy to "accidentally" misuse the exponentiation rules) so I went back and just took logs of the orginal.  Harder to do that way, but less risky.

Comment: okay so `log` should be taken to the original equation using the identity $\log (z^w) = w\log (z) + 2I \pi n$. Am I correct?
But if we do this way the `2*I*n*pi` terms gets cancelled leaving behind the real solutions

Comment: You get $2^4=2^{15x}\implies 4\ln2=15x\ln2+2in\pi$ or $x=\frac4{15}+in\frac{2\pi}{\ln2}$ as solutions.